# Assigning array elements to different UILabels in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have an array with 3 elements. And I have three UILabels. Now, I want each element in an array to be set to each UILabel. I have tried so many ways. But, could not come up for the solution.

For example, 
var properties = [data, talk, text]
and three labels : dataLabel, talkLabel and textLabel

So, I want:-

```
dataLabel.text = data 
talkLabel.text = talk
textLabel.text = text
```

I tried this,

```
properties.forEach { property in
    [dataLabel, talkLabel, textLabel].forEach {
       $0?.text = property
   }
}
```

I know, it will assign the same array element to all of the UILabels.

Comment: Unless you have 10s of different properties, I wouldn't recommend changing this to a loop like this. KISS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let lbls = [dataLabel, talkLabel, textLabel]
let arr = ["1","2","3"]
lbls.indices.forEach {
   lbls[$0] = arr[$0]
}
```

**OR**

```
zip(lbls, arr).forEach { $0.text = $1 }
```

Comment: zip is way nicer IMO, I would remove the first snippet entirely

Comment: Thank you Sh_Khan!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
var properties = [data, talk, text]
var labels = [dataLabel, talkLabel, textLabel]

for(index, element) in properties.enumerated() {
   labels[index].text = element
}
```